# How to echo a string that contains quotes without modifying the contents of the string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I wish to echo a string that contains quotes and new line characters, such as " "What do we say to the God of Death?\nNot today." "

```
echo -e " "What do we say to the God of Death?\nNot today." "
```

Won't work, of course.

What could I do, other than adding /s to the inside quotes, to have an output showing this:

```
"What do we say to the God of Death?
Not today."
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot enclose the same set of quotes within a pair of quotes without escaping.

The simplest option is to make use of [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html):

```
 echo -e $'"What do we say to the God of Death?\nNot today."'
```

It'd produce:

```
"What do we say to the God of Death?
Not today."
```

If you wanted to use only double quotes, then you'd need to escape the ones that you need to print:

```
echo -e "\"What do we say to the God of Death?\nNot today.\""
```

Comment: Would this still work if the quote itself used single quotes instead of double quotes? For example: ' 'What do we say to the God of Death?\nNot today.' '

Comment: @Regnarg I guess that the first line should answer that.

Comment: Ah, did not see that earlier

Comment: @Regnarg And the last line, gives an example using the same set of quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
echo -e '"What do we say to the God of Death?'"\n"'Not today."'
```

Example:

```
$ echo -e '"What do we say to the God of Death?'"\n"'Not today."'
"What do we say to the God of Death?
Not today."
```

The strings enclosed within single quotes are won't get parsed in `echo` command.So this `"What do we say to the God of Death?` won't get parsed. And the strings enclosed within double quotes would be parsed. So this `\n` get parsed.